# Turn off automatic preview in apple mail

Tags: mail.app, preview

Is it possible to turn off automatic preview of attachments when composing an e-mail?

NOTE: Yes I know that I can manually ctr+select the attachment and disable preview, but I want this done automatically

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Terminal, type:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes
```

If you want to turn it off again, use

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool no
```

You may need to restart Mail after running this to change the behavior.

Comment: I get a `Command not found` when running this from terminal on a fairly new MacBook air?

Comment: Don't remove this answer; it's the best way to solve this unintuitive behavior with Mail.app. This changes the default behavior of the "attach" button in the app to do real attachments instead of inline attachments. The `Viewing` portion of that is really misleading; it affects how attachments are sent.

Comment: Note that now we must first give Terminal "Full Disk Access" in System Prefs. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/343356/70115 for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

There is an extension for Apple Mail called Attachment Tamer.  It has all kinds of settings, but the most useful is the one that defaults attachments to the icon view.

http://lokiware.info/Attachment-Tamer

It is $15 but well worth it.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @user43521's answer, there are two ways to solve this problem:

**First solution:**

If you drag-and-drop files—even images—into Mail.app's compose window, they'll be sent as real attachments (`Content-Disposition: attachment`).

**Second solution:**

If you open a terminal and enter this command, it will always make attachments real attachments:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes
```

You only need to do this once. To revert to normal behavior:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool no
```

The `Viewing` portion of this is very confusing; this affects how your outgoing mail is sent. If you receive mail with inline attachments, they'll be displayed as expected. In fact, it's even more confusing than that, because regardless of this setting, both inline and attached images that you receive will be displayed inline.

Comment: If I drag an image from Finder into a new Mail draft message, it still appears as huge image preview, same as if I click the attach button and navigate to its location.

Comment: Note that now we must first give Terminal "Full Disk Access" in System Prefs. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/343356/70115 for more detail.