# Disable preview of pdf in Mail under OS X Mavericks

Tags: mail.app, attachments

Known problem: Mail previews e.g. pdf attachments. I want to see it as symbol. I could right click and choose 'Show as symbol' but I want this as default. The old solution was typing into terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes
```

which seems not to work under Mavericks any more. Does anybody have a working solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clive Galeni has [created a Mail.app plug-in](http://clivegaleni.com/posts/view-as-icon-by-default/) that sets **View as icon** to be default:

> This update will disable attachment auto preview feature and disable inline attachments when reading messages.

It seems that there are two points of view - when composing email and when viewing.

Answer (score 8):

I found this [here](http://www.applegazette.com/apps/customize-apple-mail/) to disable PDF preview in Apple Mail, and tested in on my Mavericks.

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -boolean true
```

So your were close.

Comment: That didn't work for me, Mavericks and 7.3 Mail (which I restarted)

Comment: Works for me on OS X Yosemite and Mail 8.0.

Comment: @FooBar try it again, it works great on OS 10.9.5 and Mail 7.3 on MBA. Probably try it with Mail off first.

Comment: Nope, that didn't make it, also with Mail off. But I also read earlier that for some people it fixes the issue, for some it doesn't.

Comment: Worked for me on 10.10 yosemite.

Comment: This setting only affects how new mails are composed not how received mails are displayed, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24569/134979

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should have a look at a tiny plugin written by Clive Galeni. It can be downloaded from

- http://clivegaleni.com/posts/os-x-mail-disable-inline-attachments/

Just follow the instructions and you are good to go. I'm using OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 and Mail 8.2.

There is an updated version of the plugin. Not sure if Clive Galeni updated all of his download-links accordingly. Nonetheless, there is a link to the updated post in the link I've posted.

Comment: Just tried it under OS X 10.10.4 and Mail 8.2, does not work unfortunately.

Comment: I just installed the plugin on another machine and, unfortunately, it had no effect on the inline attachment. As it uses the identical versions of software I'm not sure about the reasons for this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, neither the terminal command nor the corresponding option in Tinker Tool work any longer, but I found [Attachment Tamer](http://lokiware.info/Attachment-Tamer/Mavericks) that should be able to fix the situation.