# Attaching files and not wanting them embedded into email body

Tags: mail.app, email

Company Director with a MacBook Air and she's having problems attaching pages files and PDF's to her e-mails. Mail keep embedding them into the message window so she cannot type, or see what she's typed in the window. Many times recipients of her messages say they are missing some of the attachments she thinks she has attached.

How can I turn off the embedding of any attachments into the message body and just displaying them as a 'file' icon somewhere rather than the contents?

Comment: You can turn off the inline preview; this should help reduce the confusion http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24569/turn-off-automatic-preview-in-apple-mail

Comment: Also - I'm not 100% sure this is duplicate so rather than asking a new question, consider editing this if it's not actually a duplicate.

Comment: You're right bmike, I will update accept and correct when I have a chance to try things.

Answer (score 2):

Using the **Terminal.app** you can set a default to turn off inline previews of attached files. The command to issue is:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes
```

You only need to issue this command once per user. Be sure to quit Mail.app first and relaunch Mail.app afterwards; otherwise the changed default may not be seen.