# Mail.app attachments show as icon or document content (inline)

Tags: mail.app, email, pdf

I get my faxes sent to me by email as a PDF file. Sometimes it shows in the email as an icon with the filename.pdf. Sometimes it shows the content of the PDF within the email (i.e., you can read it in the email).

I know that when you attach a PDF file in an email you are going to send it shows in the email as the actual PDF file. If you right click on the PDF file you can make it display as an icon.

Is there a reason some attached PDFs show as an icon and some show the contents of the PDF? Is there a setting that will force all attachments to be display the content of the actual document?

Comment: It always shows as full document just scroll down in the email.

Comment: It's not doing that.  It's either the icon or the document.  Not both.

Comment: I've seen this behavior before as well, and with just about all previous versions of OSX. No doubt there is something in a file that makes it display as an icon rather than displaying the content, just not sure what that is.

Comment: The reason this happens is because some email clients, in particular Mail.app, set the `Content-Disposition` of attachments to `inline`, even if you want it to be `attachment` (a real attachment). See my answer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/141078/35362 for more detail, although unfortunately the solutions suggested there don't always seem to work.

Comment: Note that Mail.app only sets the disposition to `inline` for things that it knows how to render inline (images, PDFs). It properly uses `attachment` for other file types  (CSV, .doc).