# How to run commands to turn off preview in Mail

Tags: macos, terminal, mail.app, defaults

I try to turn off automatic preview in Mail by following the advice in [Turn off automatic preview in apple mail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24569/turn-off-automatic-preview-in-apple-mail). But I don't know where to enter `defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes`.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off automatic preview in apple mail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24569/turn-off-automatic-preview-in-apple-mail)

Answer (score 1):

Open the Terminal app located in /Applications/Utilities and type (or paste) that command, then hit enter.